# Using a color picker on your site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Currently if I choose a new colour nothing happens. What I want as you can see is to set brushColour to the colour selected. I am using http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement
But can not seem to understand the directions. Everything works besides setting the colour to the global variable.

Here is some of what I have been trying:

```
function mouseup() {
  paint = false;
  //brushColour = document.getElementById('color').value;
  //brushColour = $('input').ColorPicker(color);
 // brushColour = $('input').ColorPickerSetColor(color);
  //document.getElementById('color').value = brushColour;
  //brushColour = $('input').ColorPickerSetColor(color).value;
 // brushColour = $('#colorpickerHolder').value;
 //brushColour = $('ColorPicker').value;
  alert(brushColour);

}
```

Here you can see what I have done and you can test it, I have an alert that tells you the hex of the color when mouse is released.Also I have some console logs for mouse click and unclick . http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

Any help on how to solve this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the value of the input box for the hex value. You can get this by using the following:

```
var brushColour = $('.colorpicker_hex>input').val()
```

Comment: Also just wondering is there a way to resize the color picker so some of the text is not blocked off?

Answer (score 0):

You should just politely ask ColorPicker to set the color to the variable on color change. :)

```
$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
  flat:     true,
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) { brushColour = "#" + hex; },
});
```